# How do i perform multinomial regression ? I have to classify students based on the program they are enrolled in. Please give me some ideas or hints

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, multiclass-classification

[image]Things I have tried.

1. Used dummy variable

`df=pd.get_dummies(data = df, columns=['Gender', 'ses', 'schtyp', 'prog'],drop_first= True)`

2. Then used test and train
   But accuracy of both test and train came 1.0

My whole code -

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
#from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\0Assignments\MNR_assign\mdata.csv")
df.columns
df.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'id'], axis =1, inplace = True)
info = df.describe()
df.prog.value_counts()
df.rename(columns = {'female':'Gender'}, inplace = True)

#le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
#df['honors']= le.fit_transform(df['honors'])

df=pd.get_dummies(data = df, columns=['Gender', 'ses', 'schtyp', 'prog'],drop_first= True)

df = df [['honors','read', 'write', 'math', 'science','Gender_male', 'ses_low',
       'ses_middle', 'schtyp_public', 'prog_general', 'prog_vocation']]

inf_n = df.describe()

df.corr()

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2)

model = LogisticRegression(multi_class = "multinomial", solver = "newton-cg").fit(train.iloc[:, 1:], train.iloc[:, 0])
help(LogisticRegression)

test_predict = model.predict(test.iloc[:, 1:]) # Test predictions

# Test accuracy 
accuracy_score(test.iloc[:,0], test_predict)

train_predict = model.predict(train.iloc[:, 1:]) # Train predictions 
# Train accuracy 
accuracy_score(train.iloc[:,0], train_predict)
```

Comment: Hello, your code seems fine to me, I don't really get what exactly is the problem here. Having accuracies of 1.0 means that your network is 100% accurate, which is a great thing everyone hopes to get when working on networks. Are you looking for another way to do it (like using another library) ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Generally when you have accuracy of 100% then the model leads to overfit. Overfit models are bad.